# Find the target Flash Player version of a parent swf?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is it possible to find out which Flash Player version was targeted to compile a swf that has loaded my swf into it?

I.e., if my game swf is targeted to version 11.2 and gets loaded into a swf that was compiled to target 10.1, how I can get access to that 10.1 target version?

Comment: It doesn't matter what target you choose, as soon as your swf is loaded into another one it runs on that parent FP target version. The first swf is the one that set the target version and there's no changing it. If the loading swf is on FP 10 and your swf is using FP11 features like Vector, Stage3D, etc... then the whole thing will crash, period.

Comment: RIght, and so I'm trying to see from my child swf what the target version of the parent swf is.  Is that possible?

Comment: Sure use Capabilities class.

Comment: Capabilities only tells the version of the Flash Player that the swf is running in.  I don't see any properties that would tell me what version was targeted at compile time.  If Flash Player 17 loads a swf that targets Flash Player 10.2 which then load my swf that targets 11.2, Capabilities will only tell me that the Flash Player is version 17.

Comment: I think it's impossible.
Why don't you detect version by using Capabilities.version and urge to update the player, if the running player is older than targeted version.

Comment: @BotMaster Agreed on crash, but `Vector`s are available in FP10, so if only vectors are used and target FP version is 10, the nested SWF will work.

Comment: I wasn't sure if Vector was introduced in a late FP9 version or FP10 version.

Comment: I can provide a way to detect the FP target that was used at compilation. Now do you want to know that just as a challenge or is there a goal behind that. The way I see it, there is nothing your loaded swf can do with that information, prove me wrong and I'll show you.

Comment: I want to be able to report it so I know what the landscape is like for my swf that needs to run inside of publishers' swfs.  Knowing the version of the Flash Player is useless to me if most publishers are targeting some ancient Flash Player and preventing me from using features of newer players.  E.g., I'd like to develop a feature that relies heavily on the ThrottleEvent, but if it turns out that the majority of swfs that my swf runs in target FP 9 or 10, it's not worth my time.

Comment: Pony up, @BotMaster.